# How to align two anchor tags with text horizontally next to each other?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm working on a website, i need to put anchortag with text side by side. I tried, but i get the two images first and then the two text horizontally.

html:

```
<div id="section">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="bt btleft" href="#"><img  src="jqe13/image/web.png" 
            id="photoSelect" />web</a>
           <a class="bt btleft" href="#"><img title="Facebook"  src="jqe13/image
   /Facebook1.png" />Download</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
  #section {
  width: 82%;
   margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
```

how can i get the image and text side by side?

Comment: Use float:left for img tag and put the txt in the span ans use float:left property for that too.

Comment: Can you show your CSS also?

Comment: @Vidia I put your code in jsfiddle and its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/g8ZbM/1/

Comment: @Vidia I think some other classes are overriding, like `bt, btleft, ul, li, photoselect`

Comment: @Vidia Can you post all CSS for `bt, btleft, ul, li, photoselect` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
  #section {
  width: 82%;
   margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display:table;
    }
#section ul li
{
    display:table-cell;
}
#section ul li a
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#section ul li a img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8ZbM/3/

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what the problem is as from what I can see it looks fine. But you could just split the links up. Your using a list but not slpitting the items up.

### HTML:

```
<div id="section">
    <ul>
        <li> <a class="bt btleft" href="#"><img  src="jqe13/image/web.png" 
            id="photoSelect" />web</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="bt btleft" href="#"><img title="Facebook"  src="jqe13/image
   /Facebook1.png" />Download</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
  #section {
      width: 82%;
      margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
      padding: 2%;
      border-radius: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  #section li {
      display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
  }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QFL4a/)

So we can split them by putting them in separate `<li>` tags and then align them using `display: inline`. This makes them in a row instead of doing downwards.