# How do I align two anchor tags inline of li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the two anchor tags to be **inline** but the 2nd  tag (trash icon) is always at next line instead of same line. I want the trash icon on same line as the name and badge. I use bootstrap and neon form

```
<div class="mail-env">
    <div class="mail-env">
        <ul class="mail-menu">
            <li class="active">
                <!--1st a tag -->
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?parents/message/message_read/" style="padding:12px;">
                    <i class="entypo-dot"></i>

                    <?php echo $this->db->get_where($user_to_show_type, array($user_to_show_type . '_id' => $user_to_show_id))->row()->name; ?>

                    <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $user_to_show_type; ?></span>
                    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right">
                        <?php echo $unread_message_number; ?>
                    </span>
                </a>

                <!--2nd a tag -->
                <a href="#"  onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?parent/message/message_delete/<?php echo $row['message_thread_code']; ?>');">
                    <i class="entypo-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image: screenshot of undesired output]

This question [How to align two anchor tags with text horizontally next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326637/how-to-align-two-anchor-tags-with-text-horizontally-next-to-each-other) 
did not help

I created a jsfiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/4jean/mhnq5w99/1/

Comment: why down vote. Did I explain wrongly

Comment: `.pull-right` is going to cause your `.badge` element to display as `block`. Either place your badge before both anchors or stop floating it.

Comment: <i class="entypo-trash pull-right"></i>

Comment: Also , you need to provide the CSS

Comment: i have removed the pull-right but it displays the trash icon below while the badge now moves to the left

Comment: which of the bootstrap css do I provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both anchor tags are displayed as blocks by neon-forms.css, so they can't be side by side:

```
.mail-env .mail-sidebar .mail-menu > li a {
    display: block;
}
```

So you could change it to inline-block, for example, but it wouldn't solve the problem anyway because of html structure: badge will stay inside of the first anchor tag.

Is it possible for you to change html to something like this?

```
<li class="active">

    <!--1st a tag -->
    <a href="#" style="padding:12px;">
        <i class="entypo-dot">.</i>
        Moses Danko
        <span class="label label-info">Parent</span>
    </a>

    <!--2nd a tag -->
    <a href="#" onclick="confirm_modal('<?php ... ?>');">
      <i class="entypo-trash"></i>Del
    </a>

    <span class="badge badge-danger pull-right">
        2
    </span>
</li>
```

And css to:

```
.mail-env .mail-sidebar .mail-menu > li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I changed the css to `inline-block` it worked thanks